# threading.Event looks really slow

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading

I am currently implementing a highly threaded application and I have a speed issue with the `threading.Event`, `threading.Condition` and others.

The most critic part of my application can be summarized by that :

- one thread is handling asynchrone send message over a socket (the consumer)
- one thread is adding content to send over the socket (the producer).

I tested many ways to do (using `Queue.Queue`, `threading.Condition` etc), and currently, the best results are based on the `threading.Event` as following :

```
class ConnectionHandler():
    """
    Attributes:
        _is_alive (bool): thread stop condition
        _event (threading.Event): sending event
        _send_queue (list[str]): list of message to send over the socket
    """

    # .../...

    def _loop_send(self):
        """ Target of the consumer thread """
        while self._is_alive:

            self._event.wait()

            while self._send_queue and self._is_alive:
                self.socket.sendall(self._send_queue.pop(0))

            self._event.clear()

    def send(self, element):
        """ Function called by the producer thread """
        self._send_queue.append(element)
        self._event.set()
```

My issue is that `send` is called nearly 100k, and it is *really* slow. I profiled my producer, and here is the PyCallGraph result :

[image]

Is there any way to make this faster ?

Comment: Have you looked into `multiprocessing`? Threading is usually slow because of the Global Interpreter Lock, all your threads are still running on one core.

Comment: This is a really short overview of my `_loop_send` implementation. Using `multiprocessing` on it would be really hard (nothing is designed for that). I would like to know if there's a solution for this first. But I was already thinking about it :)

Comment: Go back to using a Queue or your own _de facto_ queue implementation and optimize from there.  The Event implementation as shown is incorrect (race) if the producer enqueues data and sets the Event flag after the consumer has emptied the `_send_queue` but before the latter has called `clear()`.